# How can I make a recursive factorial without using multiplication?

Tags: python, recursion

this is my example of recursive using '*' operation!

```
def rec_fac(n):
   if n == 1:
       return n
   else:
       return n*rec_fac(n-1)
```

Comment: That is an odd requirement. Anyway.. `n * x`, where both are positive integers, is the same as `x + x + ..` where `x` appears `n` times. And loops can be implemented via recursion.

Comment: Suggestion: make a recursive multiplication function to get rid of the *.

Comment: Why such an arbitrary restriction?  Is this a school assignment?

Comment: PS: Your given function doesn't handle 0!, which is always defined to be 1.

Comment: thanks ! user 

steven - its not ass.
mike - thanks!

Comment: can i use "operator.mul(a,b)" for not using the * operator?

Comment: @RomeliiGaballoAlbia, just make a helper function to to the multiplication

Comment: @PadraicCunningham . yes maybe it can be use . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like a technicality, try this:

```
def rec_fac(n):
    if n == 1:
        return n
    else:
        return eval('n*rec_fac(n-1)')
```

Otherwise, you should try addition:

```
def rec_fac(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return sum([n for i in range(rec_fac(n-1))])
```

Comment: Any time. You understand the list comprehension right?