# How to get full blown of Recursive Factorial

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, recursion, spyder

Lately I found out that I can't get what I want to have, like getting the **Negative Integers** of the factorial of this:

```
def rec_fac(n):
   if n == 1:
       return n
   else:
       return n*rec_fac(n-1)
```

if you have something to add with this code.. Leave a comment =)

thanks in advance!

Comment: How is this question different from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005700/how-can-i-make-a-recursive-factorial-without-using-multiplication)?

Comment: i need the negative intergers but It cant =(

Comment: What is the expected output of `rec_fact(-1)`?

Comment: gonna try this tnx =)

Comment: The factorial function is only defined on natural numbers (integers >= 0). However, there is a related function the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) which is defined for all real numbers (except the negative integers and zero); it's also defined for complex numbers. For all positive integers n, `gamma(n) == (n-1)!`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is, but factorial is defined for natural numbers.

So to handle negative numbers, do this:

```
def rec_fac(n):
   if n < 1:
       raise NotImplementedError('no definition for rec_fact(x) for x < 1')
   if n == 1:
       return n
   else:
       return n*rec_fac(n-1)
```

Comment: but can we use like this:

= 120
rec_fac(-24):  -5 * -24
   = 24
   rec_fac(6):  -4 * 6
      = 6
      rec_fac(2): -3 * 2
         = 2
         rec_fac(2): -2 * -1

Comment: factorial is defined for natural numbers, none of which are not negative.